# How to make branch on 'git svn' with multiple source?

Tags: git, git-svn

There three source repository which is provided by SVN, I want to send back them my patches by 'git svn'.  To save the clone time here is my clone method

```
mkdir myprj
cd myprj
git svn clone -r HEAD http://repo/libFoo
git svn clone -r HEAD http://repo/libBar
git svn clone -r HEAD http://repo/src
```

When I want to add a new feature, I must enter three directories and do 'git branch'.  Is there any better method to make one global git branch?
The three repositories comes from the same base http://repo

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could go. You could use `--prefix=<prefix>` to clone multiple SVN repos into the same Git repo, but you will probably still need to create separate branches for the projects, just in one repository.

Alternatively you can use some repo-managing tool. You can find multiple if you Goolge for it. Two examples are `repo` originally developed by Google for Android (https://source.android.com/source/using-repo) and the MR (http://joeyh.name/code/mr/). Or you could make a super repository and add your repos as subrepos e. g. with Gitslave (http://gitslave.sourceforge.net/).